How to initialize a colour from a raw value in swiftUI
The below code when initialized with a raw value returns NamedColor(name: "colorName" bundle:nil) with colourName being the name of the case in the enum and the raw value being passed in being the sting representation of the colour eg "oxblood" when trying to access mainColor. All colours are currently present in my assets folder.
Theme Enum
enum Theme: String, Codable, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
    case bubblegum
    case buttercup
    case indigo
    case lavender
    case magentas
    case navy
    case orange
    case oxblood
    case periwinkle
    case poppy
    case purple
    case seafoam
    case sky
    case tan
    case teal
    case yellow
    
    var accentColor: Color {
        switch self {
        case .bubblegum, .buttercup, .lavender, .orange, .periwinkle, .poppy, .seafoam, .sky, .tan, .teal, .yellow: return .black
        case .indigo, .magentas, .navy, .oxblood, .purple: return .white
        }
    }
    var mainColor: Color {
        return Color(rawValue)
    }
    var name: String{
        rawValue.capitalized
    }
    var id: String{
        name
    }
}

I am looking for this to instead return just the color so that it can be used in my views when accessing the mainColor variable. Why is it not working?

Are all of the colors in your assets folder using uppercased names?

What is NamedColor, what exactly isn't working?

change based on below code it worked for me
import SwiftUI

enum Theme: String, Codable, CaseIterable, Identifiable {
   case bubblegum
   case buttercup
   case indigo
   case lavender
   case magentas
   case navy
   case orange
   case oxblood
   case periwinkle
   case poppy
   case purple
   case seafoam
   case sky
   case tan
   case teal
   case yellow

   var accentColor: Color {
       switch self {
       case .bubblegum, .buttercup, .lavender, .orange, .periwinkle, 
         .poppy, .seafoam, .sky, .tan, .teal, .yellow: return .black
       case .indigo, .magentas, .navy, .oxblood, .purple: return .white
       }
   }
   var mainColor: Color {
       Color(rawValue)
   }

   var name: String{
     rawValue.capitalized
   }
   var id: String{
     name
   }
  }
  struct ContentView: View {

   var orangeColorTheme = Theme(rawValue: "orange")
   var purpleColorTheme = Theme(rawValue: "purple")

   var body: some View {
       VStack {
           Text("Orange Theme")
               .background(orangeColorTheme?.mainColor)
           Text("Purple Theme")
               .background(purpleColorTheme?.mainColor)
       }
    }
  }

